# GDALException OGR failure

Tags: geojson, django-rest-framework-gis, django-drf-renderer

I am working with Django DRF and GeoDjango for a simple model which is as follows.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Company', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="bla")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='blabla')
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True, geography=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This is its serializer.py

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    distance = serializers.DecimalField(
        source='distance.km', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, required=False, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'location', 'distance']
        # read_only_fields = ['distance']


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop_set = ShopSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'shop_set']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        shop_validated_data = validated_data.pop('shop_set')
        company = Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
        shop_set_serializer = self.fields['shop_set']
        for each in shop_validated_data:
            each['company'] = company
        shops = shop_set_serializer.create(shop_validated_data)
        return company
```

everything works fine until I add `rest_framework_gis` in my settings.py file or add the following line in my shop serializer

```
serialize('geojson', Shop.objects.all(),
               geometry_field='location', fields=('name', 'address'))
```

In both the cases get GDALException OGR failure.
I have checked my versions of GDAL and Python. Both are 64 bit. And both python and GDAL are working fine.

What I basically need to do here is to convert my POINT field into json lat long response right now the response is as such (if i do not include the lines that cause error).

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cosmetica",
        "address": "somwhere",
        "location": "SRID=4326;POINT (24.896 67.182)"
    }
```

Please help.